# Google Map fragment shows the previous fragment's element

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

Title can be a bit complicated but the problem is literally as described. I'm trying to use google map fragment within a fragment stack. When the application starts the user will see a button and when the user pushes the button, current view will be replaced with map fragment. Currently, I'm able to replace the fragments but when the map fragment is shown, the view still has the button of previous fragment.Also I'm trying to replace fragments in one of the tabs of my app. Here is my code;

Map Fragment;

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);

        mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;
                try {
                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
                LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker Description"));

                // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(sydney).zoom(12).build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

Home Fragment;

```
public class HomeFragment extends RootFragment {

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Obtain the shared Tracker instance.

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_tab, container, false);

        Button go = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_go);
        go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MapFragment.class);
                //startActivity(intent);
                enterNextFragment();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
    }
    private void enterNextFragment() {
        // Pushing MapView Fragment
        Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this.getContext(), MapFragment.class.getName());
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_mainLayout, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

}
```

Map Layout;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Home Fragment;

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeFragment"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:id="@+id/fragment_mainLayout">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_go"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
    android:text="GO"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Have you check my answer ?

Comment: I solved the case by not using the map as fragment. I've created another view and call it from an activity. When the user presses the go button, it will start another activity not replace the current view.

Answer (score 0):

> Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for
>   example to change the content based on a user event. All
>   Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated
>   Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

Your fragments shouldn't communicate directly according to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface).

If you've managed to communicate with your fragments considering the documentation. Then you can use this simple method to be able to change and reuse any fragment.

In your host activity :

```
private void changeFragment(Fragment frag, boolean saveInBackstack) {
    String backStateName = ((Object) frag).getClass().getName();

    try {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (manager.findFragmentByTag(backStateName) == null) {
            //fragment not in back stack, create it.
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, frag, backStateName);

            if (saveInBackstack) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Change Fragment: addToBackTack " + backStateName);
                transaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Change Fragment: NO addToBackTack");
            }

            transaction.commit();
        } else {
            manager.popBackStack();
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException exception) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to commit fragment, could be activity as been killed in
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not the answer i was looking for and didn't solve my case.

Answer (score 0):

just add `android:background="@android:color/white"` on the main view of the map_layout `xml` file

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution;

Home Fragment;

```
public class HomeFragment extends RootFragment {
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Obtain the shared Tracker instance.
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_tab, container, false);
        Button go = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_go);
        go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MapFragment.class);
                if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "GPS is Enabled in your devide", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(intent);
                } 
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

MapFragment (it is now fragmentActivity not fragment);

```
public class MapFragment extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    // private GoogleMap map;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private Marker marker;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);



    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
        googleMap = mMap;
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        Location location = null;
        try {
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));

        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if (location != null) {
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                    .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                    .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                    .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }
    }
}
```